# Adsence is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, adsense-api

Hi sorry this is my first time implementing the ads on my website but its not showing please check the screenshot below thanks and also my account is approved

[image: screenshot]

Comment: error 403 from server is not your fault as long as you've setup everything correctly.

Comment: 403 is "Forbidden" which suggests invalid credentials. Because there's no code or any other details in the question, there's not much more that can be said.